# WordPress get_the_content get child element like p value

Tags: the-content

I am developing web site by wordpress in case my problem
I want to remove h1 and h2 tag in from main page.
I want to get only child p tag by `get_the_content()`

```
<p id="main">
  <?php 
  echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(),20, '...' );  ?>
</p>
```

Main Page get the content from this page

```
<h1 class="entry-title">Set and Furniture Design</h1>
<h2 class="green-pd">Set Design</h2>
<p id="para">A Bachelor pad was to be designed for a cookery show called 'Cook na kaho' for the Star One TV channel. Props for same were purchased from various home stores and the set was installed with in four days of starting work.</p>
<h2 class="green-pd">Furniture Design</h2>
<p>The 600mm X 1500mm rectangular centre table used the Indian screen called jaaliwork as supports to the table top for breaking the monotony of solidity and straight lines.</p>
```

Please help me

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress function **get_the_content** automatically remove html tags from the content, So fetch only **p** tag content is not possible with using this function. you can use **post excerpt** to fulfill your requirement.

**Each post has section in admin called Excerpt**
*It you are unable to see the section in the admin please check **screen option** while editing the post*

```
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
```

Comment: Please require code